# How to make reshape2::acast throw an error upon variable aggregation?

Tags: r, reshape2

```
> DF = data.frame(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[4:5])[-3,], value=1:5)
> DFa = rbind(DF, c("A","D",6))
> DF
  Var1 Var2 value
1    A    D     1
2    B    D     2
4    A    E     3
5    B    E     4
6    C    E     5
> DFa
   Var1 Var2 value
1     A    D     1
2     B    D     2
4     A    E     3
5     B    E     4
6     C    E     5
61    A    D     6
```

The following works as expected:

```
> reshape2::acast(DF, Var1~Var2, value.var="value")
   D E
A  1 3
B  2 4
C NA 5
```

For the case where an aggregation is performed, I would prefer the function call to throw an error instead of just writing a message:

```
> reshape2::acast(DFa, Var1~Var2, value.var="value")
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  D E
A 2 1
B 1 1
C 0 1
```

How to wrap the 2nd call to throw an error instead of displaying the message?

I've tried some combinations of `capture.output()` and `sink()`, but I'd like to have the result of the call in my result variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages are part of the [condition system](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html) in R, and can be handled using the appropriate functions. As a consequence, this works:

```
withCallingHandlers(reshape2::acast(DF, Var1~Var2, value.var="value"),
                    message = stop)
```

Incidentally, this is a reason to strongly prefer using `warning` and `message` over `cat` for such things.